# quickest way to transfer iPhone photo to "/tmp"

Tags: photos.app

The Photo app has so many features, I can't figure-out this basic task:

1. take photos with iPhone.
2. save photos to `/tmp`

I've been copying/pasting pics into emails, then emailing myself, to get my pics into my local drive. Surely there is a simpler way.

btw: What is the setting to stop "Photo" from launching every time I plug-in my iPhone?

Comment: /tmp is for temporary files and can be deleted during a boot - do you really want that?

Comment: @Mark First, I just want the photos on my local disk somewhere. Next, I'll sort-out where to put them. So, this would be good: "$HOME/tmp"

Comment: Why not use the OS X Photos.app - the photos will sync to it

Comment: @Mark But, where does it "sync" to? ex: the pictures are not placed in "~/Pictures". What if I wanted to sell my MacBook on eBay (just kidding), and I wanted to upload pictures of it. So, I take the pictures of the MacBook with my iPhone, then... where are the pictures for me to upload to eBay? Are they "PNG", "JPG"? I don't want to learn about "Albums", "Projects", "Books", "Cards", social media hooks, just to save my photo to disk ... For ex: I want my photos stored to a local disk such that, I could tar, compress then, and then put them in cloud storage on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, I will ignore the "accepted" methods, such as Photo Stream.

Your question is still somewhat generic, as "quickest" can mean different things to different people in different situations.

- If you are physically near your Mac, **AirDrop**. Here is [an apple support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204144) explaining the procedure.
- With a USB cable, connect your iphone to your Mac and open the **Image Capture** application. Depending on your settings and OS versions, you may need to grant permission on the device. You can select one or many photos, and choose import, or just drag them into a folder. There is an option to delete them from the phone after transfer as well.
- Without a USB cable, your method is actually what I would recommend, although with a twist. I attach the images to an email, then **save it as a draft**, retrieve the emails from the draft on my Mac, then delete the draft. This has the added benefit of not creating a copy of the email in your sent folder. It seems like this might be important to you as your concern with standard sharing methods is unknown "leakage."